# How can I test a conditional in a specific column of a csv file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I've figured out how to iterate through a specific column within a csv file with n columns. But now I want to create a conditional and I'm not sure how.

The column in question is a column of days of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc.). I want to write code so that my iteration counts all the Mondays, all the Tuesdays, so and so forth. This is what I wrote up and I get a syntax error.

```
mon = 0
# print (df)

days_week = df.iloc[4:,2]
# print(days_week)
for i in days_week:
    if i == "MONDAY"
    mon+=1
```

The data type for this particular column right now 'object'. So I figure I need to change it to strings?

Comment: The syntax for `if` is very like that of `for` loops -- you'll need a colon `:` at the end of the `if` statement, and to indent the next line. But JALO's answer solves everything nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check pandas value_counts function for series data:

[value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

e.g. say df['days'] contains your data, then:

`df['days'].value_counts()` will give you counts for each of the days.

Comment: Unbelievable, thank you so much! This is so much more efficient than what I was thinking of doing :)

Comment: You are most welcome! There are many features in pandas which you will be pleasantly surprised to experience as you go forward. If you need any help, the community is anyways there :)